# How do I build a alphabetical word scoring in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my data

```
No  Number
1.  Abe
2.  Edab
```

Here's what I expected

```
No  Number    Score
1.  Abe           9
2.  Edab         12
```

This is because:

`a=1, b=2, e=5`, so `Abe = a + b + e = 8`

`e=5, d=4, a=1, b=2` so `Edab = e + d + a + b = 12`

iam expect the scoring rules is `a= 1` , ... , `z =26`

Comment: what have you done and where you stuck? show us your code.

Comment: I do `str.extract` one by one word, just too messy to write here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little numpy `view` magic.

```
v = df.Number.str.lower().values.astype(str).view(np.int32).reshape(len(df), -1) - 96
v[v < 0] = 0
df['Score'] = v.sum(axis=1)
```

```
df
    No Number  Score
0  1.0    Abe      8
1  2.0   Edab     12
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) for integer representing the Unicode code point in nested list comprehension with `sum`:

```
df['Score'] = [sum([ord(char.lower()) - 96 for char in x]) for x in df['Number']]

print (df)
    No Number  Score
0  1.0    Abe      8
1  2.0   Edab     12
```

If want working only with `a-z` values:

```
df['Score'] = [sum([ord(char.lower()) - 96 for char in x]) 
              for x in df['Number'].str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=False)]
```

Thank you, @Jon Clements for another modification of solution:

```
df['Score']=df.Number.str.lower().str.extractall('([a-z])')[0].apply(ord).sub(96).sum(level=0)
```

Comment: Slight variation keeping in the same vain as `.str.extract`... `df.Number.str.lower().str.extractall('([a-z])')[0].apply(ord).sub(96).groupby(level=0).sum()`

Comment: @JonClements - It looks nice, also `groupby(level=0).sum()` should be `.sum(level=0`. Thank you.

Comment: Ahh... I'd forgotten you can use `level` with `sum`... thanks for the reminder!